# How to change layers in OpenLayers 3 with radio buttons?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, layers

I work on my map with more layers as source, I use inputs to set source layer. I need to change **layer** value.

I have inputs type radio :

```
<input type="radio" id="1" name="4"> 
<input type="radio" id="2" name="4"> 
<input type="radio" id="3" name="4">
```

I need to change value of my :

```
  var layer = "a"
```

By click on the radio inputs. In this rule :

**id="1"** is **layer = "a"**

**id="2"** is **layer = "b"**

**id="3"** is **layer = "c"**

**var layer** is my source layer to my map.

Comment: What JavaScript have you tried and what errors or issues do you get? A comment on your HTML is that the input elements don't seem correct, you should have a value attribute I think, something like  `<input type="radio" name="4" id="1" value="a" >`